# ES5 object conversion

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

how can I construct the favMap object in ES5 so that it returns the same data? Currently I am creating it using EcmaScript2015 syntax and it doesn't work in IE.

```
var company = "Toyota,Honda,Ford";
var companyArray = company.split( "," );

const favMap = {  
  [companyArray[0]]: ["Sedans"],  //this syntax gives error in Internet Explorer
  [companyArray[1]]: ["Suvs"]
};

console.log(favMap);
```

The error is "Expected identifier, string or number". Run this code in the console of Internet Explorer to see the error.

Comment: what is the error you're getting ?

Comment: I don't think so there is any error in your code

Comment: The error is Expected identifier, string or number @CodeManiac . Run it in the console of internet explorer.

Comment: Seems like IE doesn't support computed property names in object literals. So why don't you do it the old way, create an object and then add the properties.

Comment: check this and run this code =>  shorturl.at/duzLN

Comment: can you show me please @Thomas

Comment: Internet explorer doesn't support this syntax 

you can check browser support here   .... https://caniuse.com/#search=destructuring%20assignment

Comment: @AnkitHalder this is not destructuring assignment

Comment: @netchi sorry but don't have internet explorer But i don't see any error here with your code, and everything you're using is being supported in IE as well

Comment: @CodeManiac what is the name of this syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computed property names [are not supported in IE](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_object_initializer_computed_property_names).

You could achieve the same thing by declaring an empty object and then assigning the properties via bracket syntax:

```js
const company = "Toyota,Honda,Ford";
const companyArray = company.split( "," );
const favMap = {};

favMap[companyArray[0]] = ['Sedans'];
favMap[companyArray[1]] = ['Suvs'];

console.log(favMap);
```